# Using local class in practice

Tags: java, inner-classes, nested-class

When should we use local classes? The **Best practice** approach?

Is it possible to make them abstract or static?

Any other solution to avoid them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/whentouse.html) :

> As mentioned in the section Nested Classes, nested classes enable you
>   to logically group classes that are only used in one place, increase
>   the use of encapsulation, and create more readable and maintainable
>   code. Local classes, anonymous classes, and lambda expressions also
>   impart these advantages; however, they are intended to be used for
>   more specific situations:
>
> **Local class**: Use it if you need to create more than one instance of a class, access its constructor, or introduce a new, named type
>   (because, for example, you need to invoke additional methods later).
>
> **Anonymous class**: Use it if you need to declare fields or additional methods.
>
> **Lambda expression**:
>
> - Use it if you are encapsulating a single unit of behavior that you    want to pass to other code. For example, you would use a lambda
>     expression if you want a certain action performed on each element of
>     a collection, when a process is completed, or when a process
>     encounters an error.
> - Use it if you need a simple instance of a functional interface and    none of the preceding criteria apply (for example, you do not need a
>     constructor, a named type, fields, or additional methods).
>
> **Nested class:**  Use it if your requirements
>
> - are similar to those of a local class, you want to make the type more    widely available, and you don't require access to local
>     variables or    method parameters.
> - Use a non-static nested class (or inner class) if you require access    to an enclosing instance's non-public fields and methods.
>     Use a    static nested class if you don't require this access.

You can define a local class in a method body, a for loop, or an if clause. They are similar to Inner class, because they cannot define or declare any static members.

Also they are non-static because they have access to instance members of the enclosing block.

Also read this [document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html) for purpose of Local Classes.

Comment: A local class is not the same as a nested class.  A local class is a class which is defined inside the body of a method, and therefore is only usable in that method.

Comment: @VGR could you provide more details?

Comment: @MedBesbes JDK documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html

Answer (score 2):

A local class is much like a local variable.  You would create a local class if that class is only useful within a single method.

They can be declared abstract, but not static.  As you might expect, a local class in a static method cannot access non-static instance fields or methods of the enclosing class.

There is no reason to avoid them, if they correctly and cleanly help you accomplish a task.

One use I've found is the construction of a Swing menubar hierarchy:

```
private JMenuBar buildMenuBar() {

    class MenuAction extends AbstractAction {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            // Deliberately empty.
        }
    }

    Action fileMenuAction = new MenuAction();
    Action editMenuAction = new MenuAction();
    Action viewMenuAction = new MenuAction();
    Action helpMenuAction = new MenuAction();

    localizer.configure(fileMenuAction, "menu.file");
    localizer.configure(editMenuAction, "menu.edit");
    localizer.configure(viewMenuAction, "menu.view");
    localizer.configure(helpMenuAction, "menu.help");

    JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu(fileMenuAction);
    JMenu editMenu = new JMenu(editMenuAction);
    JMenu viewMenu = new JMenu(viewMenuAction);
    JMenu helpMenu = new JMenu(helpMenuAction);

    // etc.
}
```

No other method will need the MenuAction class, so I made it local to the buildMenuBar method.